# jQuery toggle series of divs individually with one function

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

## What I have:

I have a FAQ list made up of links (questions) that toggle the hiding/showing of a corresponding paragraph (answers). An individual function is used for each link/paragraph (question/answer)

## What I need:

I'd like to achieve this using one function rather than writing a function for each link/paragraph (question/answer).

## My current code:

**HTML:**

```
<!--Q1-->

<p class="faq-question-container">
    <a href="#" id="q1">Some question</a>
</p>

<p class="faq-answer" id="a1">Some answer</p>

<!--Q2-->

<p class="faq-question-container">
    <a href="#" id="q2">Some question</a>
</p>

<p class="faq-answer" id="a2">Some answer</p>

<!--etc.-->
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.faq-answer').hide();

//Q1

$("#q1").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#a1').slideToggle();
});

//Q2

$("#q2").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#a2').slideToggle();
});

//etc.
```

## My question:

How do I streamline the above jQuery code into one function?

## What I've tried:

```
jQuery("#faq-question-container a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).next('#faq-answer').slideToggle();
});
```

Does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code, the main changes to bring are

- to fix the class selectors
- to go up before looking for the next element

This gives this code :

```
jQuery(".faq-question-container a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).closest('.faq-question-container').next('.faq-answer').slideToggle();
});
```

Another solution which doesn't assume a specific HTML composition:

```
$(".faq-question-container a[id^=q]").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#a'+this.id.slice(1)).slideToggle();
});
```

How it works :

- `[id^=q]` is a selector for all elements whose id starts with `q`.
- `this.id.slice(1)` takes `95` from an id `q95`

Comment: I would personally try to avoid the `[id^=q]` part and use `.faq-question-container a` instead. Somehow selecting all ids with `q` as the first letter doesn't look too safe to me.

Comment: @holodoc neither is selecting any a element in the container but by combining both we're probably safe. Good remark anyway.

Comment: Much thanks for the speedy answer. I've opted for the first solution because it more closely matches my attempted code and because it relies on classes instead of ids which will save me a few keystrokes for the mark-up. The second solution (id selector) also works. Thanks for the options and break down. Is one solution superior to the other?

Comment: Your first solution is right. It personally avoid moving up and side in the DOM as it breaks when you change your HTML but honestly there's no real problem here. There's no significant speed differences either, all those solutions are good.